# Error: The input contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, base64, asp.net-authentication

I am using ASP .NET MVC built in template for authentication. For some customization Roles I copied the New Registration User code on another page and stored in database by following way.

```
public void adduser(AdduserModel role){
    ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser() { Email = role.Email, PasswordHash = role.Password, UserName = role.Email, EmailConfirmed = true };
    var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var response = manager.Create(appUser);
}
```

And in template AccountController looks like following

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

    // Session["UserName"] = model.Email;
    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
}
```

Both are storing Password and Email etc in password but myCode is storing in plain text and template code is storing pass in encrypted format.

When I try to login then template registered user perform properly and logged in but my code gives me following error.

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting up roles for authenticated user and then decorating the action with something like [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]?

Comment: Yes I tried but could not .may be some thing wrong .can you explain briefly ?

Comment: There are few articles which you can follow for custom roles and authentication if you don't want to use asp.net template with in-built authentication and authorization http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/custom-authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-mvc https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which area's of the code are custom, and what version of the template / asp.net identity you are using, but if you are using the standard UserManager, try:

```
ApplicationUser appUser = new ApplicationUser() { Email = role.Email, UserName = role.Email, EmailConfirmed = true };

var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

var response = manager.Create(appUser, role.password);
```

As the UserManager should handle the encryption for you.

Just pass the plaintext password when calling **manager.Create** , and don't include it in the first line (ApplicationUser) creation.